No kernel modules loaded for 82574L Ethernet controller on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a home server with a SuperMicro X9SCM-F motherboard with an Intel Xeon E3-1270 V2 processor. It also contains two different controllers for the two Ethernet ports. The first is an Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection and the other is an Intel 82574L Gigabit Network Connection. The former works fine using the e1000e drivers. However, the latter does not appear in ifconfig and also does not have a kernel module listed for it in lspci.
Any help on getting the second Ethernet connection working would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: After some debugging, the error I get from the Intel Boot Utility is:

The adapter cannot be initialized due to inaccessible device memory.

According to Intel’s website, the latest drivers are kernel-only, so I should theoretically have the latest. So, updating won’t work here.

Does sudo modprobe e1000e work?

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.

@mchid, returns status 0, but nothing changes.

@waltinator, I found this:
host1 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
host1 kernel: e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -5
